# Symfony5.2 form action on change ChoiceType

Tags: forms, symfony

How I can make an action on change choiceType in Symfony Form ?

Something like this:

```
if ($form->onChange()) {
    //action
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Symfony as your backend only notices changes when the form is submitted. Any changes to the form before you submit must be detected via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If your form maps an entity, you can add an event subscriber to check that some property was changed

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber\Doctrine

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class DoctrinePreUpdateSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate  => 'preUpdate',
        ];
    }

    private function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args): void
    {
        if ($args->getObject() instanceof SomeEntity && $args->hasChangedField('someProperty')) {

        }
    }
}
```